# "Mother of Sara, who stabbed two citizens has been releaseed". "Sara's mother, who stabbed two citizens has been released"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, american-english, british-english

**"Mother of Sara, who stabbed two citizens has been released"**

I assume in this sentence, it was sara who stabbed citizens but her mother has been released.

**"Sara's mother,who stabbed two citizens has been released"** but in this sentence, I assume it was sara's mother herself who stabbed citizens and she herself has been released.

Could you pls tell me whether I am interpreting these sentences correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is ambiguous. It could mean either. Your interpretation of the second sentence is correct.